# Understanding of Lemma of Basis and Dimension of Vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra

*Lemma.* Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$. Let $r$ be a positive integer with $r<n$, and let $v_{1},...,v_{r}$ be linearly independent elements of $V$. Then one can find elements $v_{r+1},...,v_{n}$ such that $v_{1},...,v_{n}$ is a basis of $V$.

My question is that we don't know $v_{1},...,v_{n}$ are linearly independent. Thus, how can be this is a basis of $V$?

Comment: This is precisely why this statement needs a *proof*. In the proof, it will be shown that there do exist vectors $v_{r+1},\ldots,v_n$ such that $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ are linearly independent. Of course, it's not true that an arbitrary choice will do.

Comment: @AlexProvost Thanks. Then, proof of the lemma is not obvious.

Comment: The proof is not totally obvious, we need to pick $v_{r+1} \dots v_n$ such that $v_1 \dots v_n$ is linearly independent and spans the vector space $V$. What this tells us is that if we are given any linearly independent set of vectors that does not span $V$ we can extend this set to a basis with the correct choice of vectors

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, here is a proof. Because $r < n = \dim V$, the vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_r$ span a proper, $r$-dimensional subspace of $V$. Pick any $v_{r+1}$ in the complement of this subspace. Then $v_1,\ldots,v_{r+1}$ are linearly independent: in any linear dependence relation $$a_1 v_1 + \cdots + a_{r+1}v_{r+1} = 0,$$
we should certainly have $a_{r+1} \neq 0$ by linear independence of $v_1,\ldots,v_r$. But this means that we can express $v_{r+1}$ as a linear combination of $v_1,\ldots,v_r$, a contradiction. Continue in this fashion until you have obtained $n$ vectors in total.